# Text composable using Annotated String unexpectedly takes up the same colour as a Button() placed within the same row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, android-jetpack-compose-row

I built a composable which is basically a `Row` containing an address as `Text` and a `Button` alongside it. The address contains a label within it (e.g. 'Bill To: ') and to format it slightly differently I am using the `buildAnnotatedString` function.

This is pretty straightforward, but I am noticing an issue when during the first run, the address `Text` takes the colour assigned to the `Button` composable. I have verified this by changing the `Button` colour, and each time the result is the same on the first run. On subsequent runs, the composable behaves as expected, i.e. the `Text` is rendered as black as specified in the `text-style`. Can anyone please explain why this happens or let me know if this should be logged as an issue with the Jetpack Compose team?

**Screenshot** from the emulator of the **first run** (reproduced on physical Redmi devices as well):
[image: screenshot of the issue]

**Screenshot** representing **subsequent runs** and the **expected behaviour**:
[image: screenshot of the expected behaviour]

**My Composable function:**

```
@Composable
fun CheckoutAddress(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    addressLabel: String,
    address: String?,
    onChangeClick: () -> Unit
) {
    val separator = ": "
    val addressText = buildAnnotatedString {
        appendMedium(addressLabel)
        appendMedium(separator)
        addStyle(
            SpanStyle(
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.fontSize
            ),
            start = 0,
            end = "$addressLabel$separator".length - 1
        )
        if(address.isNullOrBlank()) {
            appendColored(stringResource(id = R.string.label_not_set), color = MaterialTheme.colors.error)
        } else {
            append(address)
        }
    }
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(end = CONTENT_TO_BUTTON_PADDING.dp),
            text = addressText,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
            maxLines = 4,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )

        ChangeButton(
            onClick = onChangeClick
        )
    }
}
```

**The ChangeButton composable** (The `R.colors.default_blue` colour specified within this composable's scope is taken up by the annotated string `Text`, have changed its value and verified) :

```
@Composable
fun ChangeButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    TextButton(
        modifier = modifier,
        onClick = onClick,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors(contentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.defaultBlue))
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.label_change_button).uppercase()
        )
    }
}
```

**The Annotated String helper methods** used above:

```
fun AnnotatedString.Builder.appendMedium(text: String) {
    append(AnnotatedString(text, SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium)))
}

fun AnnotatedString.Builder.appendColored(text: String, color: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color) {
    append(AnnotatedString(
        text,
        SpanStyle(color = color)
    ))
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I tried reproducing it with [this code](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/e16f5b550be365c439a1cf261d427ff1), and it works fine to me.

Comment: @PylypDukhov reproducing it is part of the issue, I am using two of the ```CheckoutAddress()``` composables in a ```Column()```, while the first child does not exhibit this behaviour at all, the second one does on first run and after a subsequent recomposition, it too behaves as expected.

Comment: Well, that's part of the job that only you can do: remove parts of the code until it stops reproducing to localize the problem. Until I can not reproduce it, I can't help you in any way - it could be a bug or you're doing something wrong in another part of your code. The part you shared looks fine.

Comment: @devanshu_kaushik you need to provide more info about `CheckoutAddress()` usage